# .set in function is not being found in other function so it's creating an error tkinter python

Tags: python, function, tkinter

I'm trying to create a GUI, in the nav menu you can click a cascade option to open another window where you can click roll to generate a set of numbers. It comes up with error. I think it's because the function is called from another function I just don't know how to get that function to call it/ if there is any other ways to fix this. I've tried global functions and looking it up but haven't found anything other than using classes so far, which I don't know how to do.

```
line 147, in totalRolls
        txtresultsOut.set(totalRollResults)
    NameError: name 'txtresultsOut' is not defined
```

Here is the code that is relevant to it. I've called the function to skip having to input all the other code for the main gui window.

```
 def rollSix():
    s = 0
    numbers = [0,0,0,0]

    for i in range(1,5):
        numbers[s] = randrange(1,7)
        s += 1

    numbers.remove(min(numbers))
    Result = sum(numbers)
    totalRollResults.append(Result)

def totalRolls():
    rollOne()
    rollTwo()
    rollThree()
    rollFour()
    rollFive()
    rollSix()
    txtresultsOut.set(totalRollResults)

def rollw():
    rollWindow = tix.Tk()
    rollWindow.title("Dice Rolls")
    diceLabel = Label(rollWindow, text = "Click Roll for your Stats")
    diceLabel.grid(row = 0, column = 0)
    rollBtn = Button(rollWindow, text = "Roll Stats", command = totalRolls)
    rollBtn.grid(row = 1, column = 0)

    txtresultsOut = StringVar()
    resultsOut = Entry(rollWindow, state = "readonly", textvariable = txtresultsOut)
    resultsOut.grid(row = 2, column = 0)

rollw()
```

Answer (score 0):

first of all I would NOT recommend using `StringVar()`. You can use the `.get()` method of `Entry` to obtain the value inside the same. Try this way and make a `global` declaration of the Entry whose values you want to get in other functions.

EDIT------------

```py
#you can use the following code to make your entry active to be edited.
entry.configure(state='normal')

# insert new values after deleting old ones (down below)
entry.delete(0,END)
entry.insert(0, text_should_be_here)

# and finally make its state readonly to not let the user mess with the entry
entry.configure(state='readonly')
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I am misunderstanding the answer but the entry is not an input, it is a readonly state where text is being set in it to just show the results from the rollresults function, so I can't .get() anything from that entry. Also why would you recommend not using StringVar(), don't I need to use the textvariable option to get .get() to work anyway

Comment: Hi there (again!) you can use .get() without StringVar(). If you want to insert text while entry state is readonly, then you can use configure method (SHOWN IN MY ANSWER)